# How to convert LINQ nvarchar to double

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to sort a column, but the value is stored as nvarchar in the database, how can I convert it to a double so it sorts here?  I tried to do Convert.ToDouble(t.PressureChange), but it didn't work...

```
     if (column == "PressureChange")
    {
        if (sortDirection == "ascending")
            testResults = testResults.OrderBy(t => t.PressureChange);
        else
            testResults = testResults.OrderByDescending(t => t.PressureChange);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use wrong types in Database is sadly the best answer I can give. Or enumerate before ordering, which is certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could *try*

```
if (column == "PressureChange")
{
    if (sortDirection == "ascending")
    {
        testResults = testResults.OrderBy(t => double.Parse(t.PressureChange));
    }
    else
    {
        testResults = testResults.OrderByDescending
            (t => double.Parse(t.PressureChange));
    }
}
```

... but it depends whether that method is supported by LINQ to SQL. To be honest, it sounds like you've got bigger problems in terms of your design: if you're trying to store a `double` value in the database, you shouldn't be using a `varchar` field to start with. Fix your schema if you possibly can.

EDIT: Note that based on the information on [this page about LINQ to SQL and `Convert.*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882655.aspx) it looks like `Convert.ToDouble` *should* work, so please give us more information about what happened when you tried it.

Comment: that didn't work......It's an existing database that I didn't design, but it's looking like I may have to fix it.  I was just trying to find the easiest way....

Comment: Is the value correct? Monitor it and check that you acutally get the value and not the var name.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Note that this question is about LINQ to SQL, and the question you linked to was about Entity Framework.

Comment: @user1202606: "that didn't work" provides almost no useful information. Whenever you want to say that something didn't work, please provide more details - such as what happened. And in the long term, "the easiest way" is almost always fixing the underlying issue rather than working around it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I give you that point. But I think (which should be wrong), that many "function has no translation" errors co-exist in both worlds...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Some do, some don't IIRC. See my edit - it looks like Convert.ToDouble *should* be okay, but the OP didn't bother telling us in what *way* it didn't work. Off to bed now...

Comment: @JonSkeet well he tried the double.Parse, let him try the Convert.ToDouble one ;) And good night !

Answer (score 0):

Rather use TryParse to avoid exceptions. In this code I used 0.0 as a default value if it could not parse the string.

```
double temp = 0.0;
if (column == "PressureChange")
{
    if (sortDirection == "ascending")
        testResults = testResults.OrderBy(t => (double.TryParse(t.PressureChange.toString(), out temp) ? temp : 0.0)).ToList();
    else
        testResults = testResults.OrderByDescending(t => (double.TryParse(t.PressureChange.toString(), out temp) ? temp : 0.0)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of t.PressueChange? I think that is where your problem lay

Comment: @GerhardPowell no. The function can't be translated in Linq2Sql or Linq2entities. That's all. It works in Linq2Objects

Comment: You can create a Comparer that will handle the string -> real with exception handle

Comment: In the database it's nvarchar.  That is the issue.  Whoever designed the database should have made it a double.  Looks like I'll change the datatype in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but you can use an extension method like this:

```
public class StringRealComparer : IComparer<string>
{
 public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
 {
  double d1;
  double d2;
  double.tryParse(s1, out d1);
  double.TryParse(s2, out d2);
  return double.Compare(d1, d2);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a suboptimal solution. It parses twice for each comparison that is made.

Comment: @GertArnold Any suggestions in improving it?

Comment: I would not use a comparer but let a TestResult object parse its PressureChange and memoize the result in an unmapped property which is used in OrderBy.